# Por que o modificador de acesso "private" está deixando eu alterar o atributo fora da classe?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, private

Bem, eu tenho essa classe com os atributos `private`

```
class Conta {
        int numero; // Atributo
        private double saldo;
        Cliente user = new Cliente();
        private double limite; }
```

Pelo que entendi do modificador private eu só deveria ser capaz de alterar o saldo e o limite através da classe, com um método, mas isso não ocorre aqui:

```
    conta minhaConta = new conta();
    minhaConta.user.nome = "Marcelo Dos Santos";
    minhaConta.user.cpf = "12F";
    minhaConta.numero = 123;
    minhaConta.saldo = 1000; // Define o saldo
    minhaConta.limite = 1000;
    minhaConta.deposita(100);
    minhaConta.saca(0);
    minhaConta.saldo = 10; // Altera o saldo fora da classe mesmo com private
    System.out.println(minhaConta.saldo); // Retorna 10 e não 1000
```

Por que isso acontece?

Código completo:

```
public class ExerciciosConta {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class Cliente {
            String cpf;
            String nome;
        }

        class conta {
            int numero; // Atributo
            private double saldo;
            Cliente user = new Cliente();
            private double limite;

            void saca (double quantidade) {
                if(quantidade <= this.saldo) {
                    this.saldo -= quantidade;
                    System.out.println("R$" + quantidade + " retirados com sucesso! Seu saldo atual é de: R$ " + this.saldo);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Sem saldo suficiente para o saque.");
                }
            }
            void deposita(double quantidade) {
                if(this.saldo + quantidade <= this.limite) {
                    this.saldo += quantidade;
                    System.out.println("R$" + quantidade + " depositados com sucesso! Seu saldo atual é de: R$ " + this.saldo);
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Você não pode depositar esta quantidade de dinheiro, pois irá atingir o limite da conta. Você pode depositar R$" + (this.limite - this.saldo));
                }
            }

            boolean transfere(conta destino, double valor) {
                if(this.saldo >= valor) {
                    this.saldo -= valor;
                    destino.saldo += valor;
                    System.out.println("Transferência de R$" + valor + " realizada com sucesso! Seu saldo atual é de: R$ " + this.saldo);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Seu saldo é de: R$ " + this.saldo + ". Você não tem saldo para essa transferência!");
                    return false;
                } 

            }
        }
        Cliente clienteUm = new Cliente();
        clienteUm.nome = "Marcelo dos Santos Cardoso";
        clienteUm.cpf = "12F";

        Cliente clienteDois = new Cliente();
        clienteDois.nome = "Marcio de Sá";
        clienteDois.cpf = "13F";

        conta minhaConta = new conta();
        minhaConta.user.nome = "Marcelo Dos Santos";
        minhaConta.user.cpf = "12F";
        minhaConta.numero = 123;
        minhaConta.saldo = 1000; // Define o saldo
        minhaConta.limite = 1000;
        minhaConta.deposita(100);
        minhaConta.saca(0);
        minhaConta.saldo = 10; // Altera o saldo de fora da classe
        System.out.println(minhaConta.saldo); // Retorna 10 e não 1000


        conta contaDoOutro = new conta();
        contaDoOutro.user.nome = "Marcio De Sá";
        contaDoOutro.user.cpf = "13F";
        contaDoOutro.saldo = 2000;
        contaDoOutro.numero = 132;
        contaDoOutro.limite = 5000;

        contaDoOutro.transfere(minhaConta, 3000);

        System.out.println(minhaConta.user.cpf);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É simples, o código mistura coisas que são diferentes. Você colocou uma classe dentro da outra, aí ela acaba tendo acesso. Só que isto é errado, as classes devem ser separadas, de acordo com o que deseja. O que você fez é o que se chama *inner class*, que tem por objetivo justamente compartilhar o estado entre a classe mais externa e a classe mais interna. Isto é útil para um padrão bastante específico, que não é o que deseja. Crie as classes de forma separadas e terá o resultado que busca. Ou seja, crie `Conta` e `Cliente` fora de `ExerciciosConta` que é apenas uma classe utilitária.